# Do we have any APEX code scanner?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, code

Need a tool to analyse apex code vulnerabilities and provide solutions.

Comment: If you mean a profiler then there is none. You need to conform with the apex best practices and test your code using unit tests. Properly written unit tests analyze and test your code quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Salesforce as lots for tools for doing code scan check.

One of them is checkmarx

Here is the link you can have a try

https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner.

You can give a try for the below link as well.

https://www.code-scan.com/

If you are good in using eclipse there is plugin **Apex security scanner - Eclipse Plug-in**

Here is the link
https://www.apexscanner.com/EclipsePlugin/EclipsePluginRequest.aspx